# Google Analytics module is not tracking site search

Tags: 6, search, google-analytics

I have a site that is using the Google Analytics (GA) module. It's happily tracking data to GA. However, I can't seem to get Site Search working.

The site uses Apache Solr. A search results page for the query "test" is:
/sitesearch/test

1. I've enabled "Track internal search" in the Google Analytics module config page
2. I've enabled "Site search Tracking" in GA
3. I've set the query parameter to "sitesearch" in GA
4. I've unchecked "Strip query parameters out of URL" in GA
5. I've confirmed that if I manually hit this URL, it pings a track in GA:
   /sitesearch/test?sitesearch=test
   (Any URL on the site with ?sitesearch=test works.)

I'm out of ideas. What could be causing this to fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that Google Analytics only supports site search tracking if the path is "search/something", not "sitesearch" as we use on my client's site.

Line 138ish from googleanalytics.module:

```
if (module_exists('search') && variable_get('googleanalytics_site_search', FALSE) && arg(0) == 'search' && $keys = search_get_keys()) {
  $url_custom = '(window.googleanalytics_search_results) ? ' . drupal_to_js(url('search/'. arg(1), array('query' => 'search='. drupal_urlencode($keys)))) . ' : ' . drupal_to_js(url('search/'. arg(1), array('query' => 'search=no-results:'. drupal_urlencode($keys) .'&cat=no-results')));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like query param changed to "keys" so that should be updated in the GA interface